# How to play sound/audio from phone storage on ionic 7?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic7

How to play sound/audio from phone storage on ionic 7?

I tried using [cordova-plugin-nativeaudio](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio) like below

```
const url = await Filesystem.getUri({
    directory: Directory.Documents,
    path: 'test.ogg',
})

window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadSimple('test', url.uri, function (msg) {
}, function (msg) {
    console.log('error: ' + msg);
});

window.plugins.NativeAudio.play('test');
```

and it's returns:

```
Msg: error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/test.ogg
```

If the path is from my app public path it works. But if it from phone storage it doesn't work.

On the documentation says:

> assetPath - the relative path or absolute URL (inluding http://) to
> the audio asset.

But why I tried absolute URL of phone storage still fail? I already give storage permission to my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614794/ionic-2-ios-native-audio-does-not-find-a-file-in-cordova-file-datadirectory) that seems cordova-plugin-nativeaudio is not work with phone storage. But I know the work around just using HTML5 audio:

```
import {Filesystem, Directory} from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import {Capacitor} from '@capacitor/core';

const url = await Filesystem.getUri({
    directory: Directory.Documents,
    path: 'secrets/test.ogg',
})

const fileSrc = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(url.uri);
const audio = new Audio(fileSrc);
audio.play();
```

Actually I tried `new Audio(url.uri)` but doesn't work(file permission issue), after I convert that path using `convertFileSrc()` method first, it works.